# Sitecore WFFM - fixing wrong wizard titles

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

I use the WFFM module for a client. The problem is just that there are wrong texts in the wizard for inserting a form:

1. Select "Insert an existing form", press next.
2. The subtitle under "Select a Form" is now "Copy an *existing* form." This is misleading as the user expects to insert a form, without duplicating it.
3. The last step in the wizard states "Confirm the configuration of the *new form*." which is equally misleading.

Is there any way I can correct this?

**Info:**

- Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 160519)
- Web Forms for Marketers 8.1.rev. 160523

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the form selection screens. This _used_ to be an issue in previous version of WFFM but was resolved in 8.0 update-6

Answer (score 0):

1. Login `“Desktop”` mode
2. Select `“core”` database
3. Open `“Content Editor”`
4. Search for required text e.g. “*Copy an existing form*”
5. Find right Dictionary item
6. Set its “Phrase” field to the new value
7. Save item. Get back to `"master"` database. Now WFFM wizard should
   show new values.

Comment: This does not work. WFFM does not use the database to save these strings.

Comment: Have you found the "/sitecore/system/Dictionary/C/Copy an existing form" item in the core database? Set its "Phrase" field to "some text" value. Save the item. Open WFFM wizard. Now you should see "some text" instead of "Copy an existing form" in the subtitle under "Select a Form". Just have checked on "Web Forms for Marketers 8.1.rev. 160523" and it works well.